# Delphi: AES CBC encryption compatible with PHP mcrypt_encrypt

Tags: php, delphi, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt data in Delphi then decrypt it in PHP, but the Delphi output differs from what I get with PHP, so I am first testing whether both the PHP and Delphi output from encrypting a string is the same:

Delphi encryption, using DCPcrypt:

```
Uses DCPcrypt2, DCPblockciphers, DCPrijndael;

var Cipher : TDCP_rijndael;
     Data, Key, IV : Ansistring;
begin
  key := '12345678901234567890123456789012';
  iv  := '1234567890123456';
  Data := 'thisis128bitstxt';

  Cipher := TDCP_rijndael.Create(nil);
  Cipher.Init(Key[1],128,@IV[1]);
  Cipher.EncryptCBC(Data[1],Data[1],Length(Data));
  Cipher.Free;

  With TMemoryStream.Create do begin
    Write(Data[1],Length(Data));
    SaveToFile('z:\delphi');
    Free;
  end;
```

Now the code in PHP:

```
<?php
    $source = "thisis128bitstxt"; //128-bits block
    $key = "12345678901234567890123456789012"; // 32
    $iv = "1234567890123456"; // 16
    $source = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$key,$source,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);
    $out = fopen ('php', 'w');
    fwrite ($out, $source);
    fclose ($out);
?>
```

Results:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Why do so many people think that text and binary are interchangeable.

Comment: Reworked the question a bit, comparing only binary data to rule out base64 issues.

Comment: The Delphi encryption is correct, PHP is incorrect.

Comment: Nope. You still treat text as if it were binary.

Comment: everything is "binary" in the end anyway

Comment: I've written an alternative AES encode/decode [here](http://yoy.be/aesdes.html) but I don't have the CBC-bit (yet...)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$source = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$key,$source,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);
```

to:

```
$source = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$KEYkey$source,MCRYPT_ENCRYPT,$iv);
```

Comment: `mcrypt_cbc` is deprecated, you should provide a solution based on `mcrypt_encrypt`